# jQuery ajax callback function does not fire as soon as the page loads

Tags: jquery

I am novice in jQuery and experiencing a problem. In the simple code snippet below I am making ajax call to return current date time.If I click the button as soon as the page loads, I get the message "Button Clicked". The WebMethod also gets called. However I do not get the message "success" which seems to me like the callback function on success is not getting called.But things work fine when I wait for a few seconds after the page loads and then click the button. Does this mean that jQuery script is taking time to load? If that's the case, how did I get the message "Button Clicked" when I clicked the button soon after the page loaded.

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#btnClick").click(function () {
                  GetDate();
              });
          });

       function GetDate() {
            alert("Button clicked!");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetDate",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });
        }
</script>

<form runat="server">
   <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" />
</form>

//WebForm.aspx.cs
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetDate()
{
  return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `GetDate` javascript function? Can you show your real code?

Comment: Apologies..have updated it in the code snipped now.

Comment: Alright, now that you have shown your real code, it's clear where the problem is. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have subscribed to the `.click()` event of the button but you haven't canceled the default action. So when the user clicks on this button, ASP.NET performs a PostBack to the server and redirects you away leaving no time for your AJAX request to execute.

Here's how to cancel the default action of the button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnClick").click(function () {
        GetDate();
        return false; // <!-- Cancel the default action of the button
    });
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnClick").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();  // <!-- Cancel the default action of the button
        GetDate();
    });
});
```

Also you don't need the `dataType: 'json'` property in the AJAX request. You have set the contentType header to `application/json` meaning that the Page Method that you are calling will return JSON and set the proper Content-Type response header. So jQuery will use this header and already parse the result for you in the success callback where you could directly display it:

```
success: function(msg) {
    alert('Success. The result is ' + msg.d);
}
```

Notice how I have used the `.d` property in the success callback. That's due to the nature of how ASP.NET Page Methods infrastructure serialize the JSON response. It will look like this:

```
{"d":"12/30/2012 12:45:02 PM"}
```

Comment: Excellent..cancelling the default action indeed solves the problem. But I dont seem to understand something. From my original code, why is it that after waiting for a few seconds and then clicking on the button does not cause the problem?

Comment: Just incase my question wasnt clear...I faced that issue only when I clicked the button immediately after the page loaded. Clicking on the button after a few seconds did not cause the issue. Why is that? The normal button behaviour would execute every time I click the button.